# Go Gin Gorm how can you combine both has many and belongs to?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm, go-gin

I have two structs Thread and User. User currently has a 'has many' relationship with Thread. The two structs are:

```
type Thread struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"threadId"`
    Title     string    `gorm:"not null" json:"title"`
    Body      string    `gorm:"not null" json:"body"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`

    // Foreign keys
    UserID uuid.UUID `json:"userId"`

    // Has many association
    Comments []Comment `json:"comments"`

    // many to many associations
    Interests     []Interest `gorm:"many2many:thread_interests;" json:"interests"`
    UsersLiked    []User     `gorm:"many2many:post_likes;" json:"usersLiked"`
    UsersDisliked []User     `gorm:"many2many:post_dislikes;" json:"usersDisliked"`
}

type User struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"userId"`
    Username   string    `gorm:"not null; unique" json:"username"`
    Email      string    `gorm:"not null; unique" json:"email"`
    FirstName  string    `gorm:"not null" json:"firstName"`
    LastName   string    `gorm:"not null" json:"lastName"`
    Password   string    `gorm:"not null" json:"-"`
    IsVerified bool      `gorm:"not null; default:true" json:"isVerified"` // change when implementing OTP
    CreatedAt  time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`

    // Has one associations
    Profile UserProfile `json:"profile"`

    // has many associations
    Threads  []Thread  `json:"threads"`
    Comments []Comment `json:"comments"`

    // many to many associations
    LikedThreads     []Thread  `gorm:"many2many:post_likes;" json:"likedThreads"`
    DislikedThreads  []Thread  `gorm:"many2many:post_dislikes;" json:"dislikedThreads"`
    LikedComments    []Comment `gorm:"many2many:comment_likes;" json:"likedComments"`
    DislikedComments []Comment `gorm:"many2many:comment_dislikes;" json:"dislikedComments"`
}
```

Is it possible for Thread struct to also have a User property? Right now it has UserID instead. I wanted to make my api in such a way that the response will have the user Owner of the thread returned in the response not just the foreign key UserID.

**UPDATE:**
I am thinking of making a new struct called ThreadResponse with all the Thread property and an additional Owner property with type User. My thought process was using the foreign key i will make another query in User table to get the user object and populate the Owner property with it. I am not sure if this is the right way to do so.

Comment: Why don't you use `JOIN` in your query?

Comment: @AminRashidbeigi Is it possible to make it in such a way where Thread will have an Owner property of type User using `JOIN`? I am quite new to GORM  I was initially thinking of making a new struct called ThreadResponse with all the Thread property and an additional Owner property with type User. My thought process was using the foreign key i will make another query in User table to get the user object and populate the Owner property with it.